# Let declarations outside of blocks in Alloy

Tags: alloy

I recently came across some Alloy models that have "let" statements that do not pertain to any block in the model. The Alloy Analyzer parses these models just fine so I know this is valid Alloy syntax. However, there is no rule in the Alloy v4 grammar posted on https://alloytools.org/download/alloy4-grammar.txt or in the grammar in Daniel Jackson's book on Alloy that says that "let" statement can appear outside of blocks. The following extract shows an example of these "let" statements.

```
let bitXorTable = {
  i: bits,
  j: bits,
  k: bitAndTable[bitOrTable[i, j], bitNotTable[bitAndTable[i, j]]]
}

pred halfAdder(m: Int, n: Int, s: Int, c: Int) {
  s = bitXorTable[m, n]
  c = bitAndTable[m, n]
}
```

I'm working on creating an ANTLR parser for Alloy and I would like to know if I should add this rule to my grammar. Could it be that these "let" statements are only valid in certain versions (newer/older) of Alloy?

Comment: I've since found that there's an Alloy grammar in the Antlr examples repository.  https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/alloy/alloy.g4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked at the grammar, but this is covered on the Alloy website under [Macros](https://alloytools.org/quickguide/macro.html)

> Untyped macros can be defined at the top level of a file. All 3 syntax are equivalent. (If parameterless, then [ ] can be omitted.)

```
 let a[x,y,z]   {...}
 let a[x,y,z] = {...}
 let a[x,y,z] = .....
```

> Macro expansion obeys proper grammar, so each argument to a macro must be an integer/boolean/set/relation or must be a (possibly partial) call to a predicate/function/macro.
>
> Macros are untyped, so in a file we can’t have 2 macros with the same name. Also, if a macro is in scope, it always overrides other possible sig/field/fun/pred with the same name (Just like when inside a paragraph if we see let x=y | F, then in F we always take x to mean y, even if globally there is some other sig x or some other field x)
>
> Lexical scoping: Inside a macro body, if you refer to a name not in the parameter list, then we will resolve it from the file that “defined” the macro, rather than resolve it from the file that “calls” the macro.
>
> Currying: if you call a macro with insufficient number of arguments, then the result is a new macro with the first N parameters filled in, like currying.

Comment: Thanks! I'll add these macros to my grammar since they are clearly part of the language.